# With CocoaPods Pod versions, what is the difference between '~> 1.2.0' and '1.2.0'?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

For example, in my Pod file I have:

`pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'`

But I also have another that looks like this:

`pod 'SwiftTheme', '0.4.1'`

What does the `~>` indicate?

Comment: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod oh oh oh reading the docs is so hard

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said in the comments, the docs answer my original question.

> ~> 0.1.2 Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2.
>   This operator works based on the last component that you specify in
>   your version requirement. The example is equal to >= 0.1.2 combined
>   with < 0.2.0 and will always match the latest known version matching
>   your requirements.

From http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod